# How do I use RStudio's new Connections tab to connect to Hive?

Tags: hive, rstudio

I am trying to use the new Connections tab inside RStudio (*Preview* *version* Version 1.1.345) to make a new connection to a Hive database.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.2     purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1    
[4] tidyr_0.7.0     tibble_1.3.3    ggplot2_2.2.1  
[7] tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] jsonlite_1.5     reshape2_1.4.2   rstudioapi_0.6  
 [4] magrittr_1.5     gtable_0.2.0     hms_0.3         
 [7] base64enc_0.1-3  xml2_1.1.1       htmltools_0.3.6 
[10] forcats_0.2.0    stringr_1.2.0    haven_1.1.0     
[13] broom_0.4.2      cellranger_1.1.0 lattice_0.20-35 
[16] bit_1.1-12       plyr_1.8.4       lubridate_1.6.0 
[19] mime_0.5         pkgconfig_2.0.1  R6_2.2.2        
[22] shiny_1.0.4      digest_0.6.12    colorspace_1.3-2
[25] bindrcpp_0.2     rprojroot_1.2    sparklyr_0.6.2  
[28] stringi_1.1.5    yaml_2.1.14      lazyeval_0.2.0  
[31] httr_1.3.1       compiler_3.4.1   bindr_0.1       
[34] bit64_0.9-7      backports_1.1.0  xtable_1.8-2    
[37] munsell_0.4.3    DBI_0.7          psych_1.7.5     
[40] modelr_0.1.1     Rcpp_0.12.12     readxl_1.0.0    
[43] dbplyr_1.1.0     parallel_3.4.1   assertthat_0.2.0
[46] blob_1.1.0       tools_3.4.1      foreign_0.8-69  
[49] odbc_1.1.1       httpuv_1.3.5     scales_0.4.1    
[52] glue_1.1.1       rlang_0.1.2      mnormt_1.5-5    
[55] nlme_3.1-131     rvest_0.3.2      grid_3.4.1
```

I have updated all my installed packages to the latest version of everything with the exception of tibble which I left at v1.3.3 (the latest version of tibble is 1.3.4 but it needs compilation so I didn't bother).

I also have these packages installed:

```
rJava v0.9-8 (the latest) and RJDBC v0.2-5 (the latest)
```

After I click on the  **New Connections** button in the Connections tab, I don't still don't see Hive as an option in the Connections dialog[image]

Yet from the image on the ([RStudio site](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010915687)), it does appear as a potential option. [image]

I am using Windows 7 Professional on a 32 bit PC (yeah yeah, I know its old but its a work-supplied laptop).

What am I missing?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a Hive ODBC driver on your machine in order for it to show up in the list. You can get one here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40886